# How to get ID of a member from a dropdown box

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the best way to get a member's ID so I can send it with an api request, currently I have a drop down menu which shows all the current members.

```
 <select name="member_id" id="member_id" className={`form-control ${memberSelected ? "is-valid" : "is-invalid"} `}  label="Member" placeholder="select" onChange={onChangeMember} required>
     <option selected disabled value="">Please select</option>
           {members[0].id && members.map((member) => {
              return ( <option key={member.id}> {member.id} {member.firstName} {member.surname} </option>
           );
       })};
 </select>
```

The only way I have so far found to be able to get the ID so I can send it to the api, is to put the member id on the dropdown, get its value and then use a split method to just get the id,

`membersId.split(" ")[0]` This works fine, but I dont really want to have the id number showing on the dropdown.

So I want to just show the name `Joe bloggs` and if they are selected on the dropdown, then this updates `membersId` with `Joe Bloggs` ID number.

Comment: You don't assign a value to the options, but if you do (`<option value={member.id}>...</option>`), you can use `document.getElementById("member_id").value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option key={member.id} value={member.id}> {member.firstName, + ' ' + member.surname} </option>
```

Then you can use *onChange* event or *document.getElementById("idName")* for catching the selected member id's

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
const handleOnChangeMember = (event) => {
   const memberId = event.target.value;
    // Do api call with member id
}

<select ... onChange={handleOnChangeMember} required>
   <option selected disabled value="">Please select</option>
   {
      members && members.map((member) =>
          <option value={member.id}>{member.firstName} {member.surname} </option>
   }
</select>
```